# Github Desktop reverting is not possible because you have unmerged files

Tags: git, github

Am pretty new to using Git (currently using Github Desktop for my unity project) and i thought everything was going fine since i was committing and pushing daily, yesterday i upgraded the project to a newer unity version, but now i regret that, so i just wanted to come back to this commit:

[image]

but whenever i choose "revert this commit", it shows me this error:

[image]

and in the changes window there are two conflicts which i also have no idea what caused them or how to fix them:

[image]

I went through similar questions to mine but most answers says "fix the conflict", the problem is that i don't what did i conflicted, nor how to fix it

Comment: Well, that's what you need to learn how to do. You started a merge, it stalled with a conflict, you are now in a half-state stuck in the middle of a merge. You must either fix the conflicted files and add them, as the message tells you, or else abort the merge.

Comment: can you please elaborate what "fix the conflict" means ? like what should i do exactly to tell it to choose one version or another ? or should i actually do some real modifications on the file itself ?

Comment: But that has been explained dozens of times here and in numerous manuals and tutorials. There is no need to spend more bandwidth on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open git terminal and run the following command-

```
git reset --hard {Your commit hash}
```

It will move the HEAD back to where you want to be. Commit hash looks like - "`4a155e5`".

Comment: thanks this worked! now am worried about something, the version that i rolled back to is one version behind the latest PUSH, so now, its asking me to PULL ORIGIN, before being able to push, am worried that i'll do something wrong, any advice please ?

Comment: Pulling from origin will fetch all your commits. You need to force push this commit to origin. Try `git push -f`.